# I want to replace one form field with another when the value of another field is equal to something

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, forms

The thing I have here doesn't work. It will just get rid of the field once choose US and doesn't go back to the choices even if choose something else.

teacher_signup.html

```
{% block content %}
<h2>Sign Up As Teacher</h2>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    {{ field | as_crispy_field}}

    {% if field.name == "country" %}
        <input type="button" value="cube" onclick="getcube()"/>  
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
</form>
<script>  
    function getcube(){  
        var county=document.getElementById("id_country").value;  
        alert(county);  
    }  
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#id_country").change(function(){
        if (this.value=="US"){
            $("#id_state").replaceWith();
        } 
    });
});       
</script>
{% endblock content %}
```

forms.py

```py
class TeacherSignUpForm(SignupForm):
    country=CountryField(blank_label='(select country)').formfield()
    # this is just doing the same thing as country=forms.CharField(max_length=20, widget=forms.Select(choices=COUNTRY_CHOICES), required=True)
    state=forms.CharField(max_length=20,required=True)
```

I want to replace the state field with 
state=forms.CharField(max_length=20, widget=forms.Select(choices=STATE_CHOICES), required=True, strip=True)
if the country=="US" and if they choose something else, then it will just show the text field.

Comment: Where do you want this to happen? Or when. 

On document load? What isn't working? There is a good amount of code that looks pretty valid at a glance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would approach it:

1. I would create both fields in your form (e.g. a `state_us` field with the select widget and `state` field with the normal text input widget). You make one of the two `hidden` initially depending on the initial value you want to give to country (or if country is initially empty, make them both hidden).
2. In the form's `clean` method, where the form is bound (i.e. there was some data submitted), you can set the appropriate field `hidden` based on the value of the country. That's so that the form with errors is rendered correctly.
3. Also in the `clean` method, you verify whether the correct field is populated depending on `cleaned_data['country']`.
4. In your template, both fields are rendered, and your javascript checks for the value of country and hides either "id_state_us" or "id_state" (and shows the other). It should also always copy the selected value for the `state_us` field to the `state` field and clear it when a different country is selected. That way the submitted `state` data always contains the state.